# How do you find the average slope over the indicated intervals?

Tags: calculus

How do you find the average slope over the indicated intervals?
The question in my book is $g(x)=4x+5$ from $x=-3$ to $x= -1$ 
what I don't understand is how do find the average slope and is there a easy way of doing math problems like this?

Comment: Average slope sounds a little funny to me.  Two more familiar ideas would be the average value of a function over an interval and the slope of a line.  Since in this case the function is a linear function, I think the answer should just be the slope of the line.

Comment: There's no need to start your question with "So my question is".  Just ask! :-)  And do you mean *average rate of change* instead of *average slope*?

Answer (score 2):

The average slope in $[a,b]$ is computed as follows
$$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$
you can see the function $f$ as the distance of a moving object from a certain point, in that case the average slope means the average speed, therefore you just compute the distance of the trajectory divided by the time.

Answer (score 1):

Slope is rise/run, that is how I was taught. So you take the value of the function at the end points and subtract, then divide be the interval length. This is the simplest way I can explain without using a formula

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean the "average rate of change."

Many students get tripped up by this without knowing it's something they already know - this is just the slope of the line that joins two points on a curve.

Remember that the slope of a line joining $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ is

$$ m = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1} $$

Oh, memories from algebra I. Now, in calculus, it is of interest to examine an average rate of change and compare that to the instantaneous rate of change - the derivative.

To find the average slope of $f$ on $[a, b]$, first find $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ and use the above formula. Done.

Comment: See my problem is I only have ever done 2 questions that involves this in algebra and they were straight lines and this one here is a curve,
is there any videos that you would be able to link me to that would walk me through how to do these kinds of questions step by step, I'm more of a visual learner and every time I look it up I end up getting lost trying to follow what the person is doing or questioning where exactly how or where they got a number from

Comment: Just look up "Average Rate of Change." You can easily visualize this as follows: plot the function, find the two points of interest and draw the line that joins the two.